# How to check and ignore message from serial port?

Tags: c#, filter, serial-port, contains

i want to ignore all messages that came to serial port except unique. i add each message to hashSet and when new message arrive i check that this messages not contains in hashSet, if this message not contains i want to print him, right now my program think that each messages arrived is unique and i don't understand why my comparing code not working, maybe somebody can help me. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace mySniffer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<String> messages = new HashSet<String>();
            SerialPort comPort = new SerialPort();
            comPort.BaudRate = 115200;
            comPort.PortName = "COM4";
            comPort.Open();
            while (true)
            {
                string rx = comPort.ReadLine(); //reading com port
                messages.Add(rx); // Add new incoming message to hashSet
                if (!messages.Contains(rx))
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(rx); // write incoming message
                }
                else { 
                    Console.WriteLine(messages.Count); // check how many messages in hashSet
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you give us a sample of the incoming strings?

Comment: Here is the sample: 0x30x980x20x00x80x2100x640x0

Comment: I can't reproduce your error like that.

Comment: try to send random numbers to serial port in a loop, i'm using arduino for this test

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in logic of code, `messages.Add(rx);` should be moved in `if` block.